# post data from table row like json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, data-retrieval

this is related to my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866862/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-row-jquery)(
NOTE: I already got some good answers there). I'm doing a program that will filter. I didn't include this question because i thought that it is easier for me to add text as long as i know how to get the data from the row. But to my dismay, I wasn't able to code a good program til now.

Im currently using this javascript code (thanks to Awea):

```
$('#out').click(function(){    
   $('table tr').each(function(){
      var td = '';
      $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){
         td = td + ' ' + $(this).text();
      });
      td = td + ' ' + $(this).find('input').val();
      alert(td);
   });
})
```

my question is: How to add text before the data from the row? like for example, this code alert 
the first row like `data1.1 data1.2 data1.3`,

then the second row like `data2.1 data2.2 data2.3`,

I want my output to be displayed like this

`[
   {"name":"data1.1","comparison":"data1.2", "value":"data1.3"},
     {"name":"data2.1","comparison":"data2.2", "value":"data2.3"},
{"name":"data3.1","comparison":"data3.2", "value":"data3.3"}
              {.....and so on......}]`

but before that happen, i want to check if all the FIRST cell in a row is not empty. if its empty, skip that row then proceed to next row.

is there somebody can help me, please...

Comment: You should add the JQuery tag, since that is a library outside of javascript itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866862/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-row-jquery/5867004#5867004) [to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866862/how-to-get-the-data-from-a-row-jquery), see http://jsfiddle.net/evbUa/1/

Once you have your data in a javascript object (`dataArray` in my example), you can write the JSON yourself, per my example, but you will find it much easier to use a library such as [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery/912247#912247) also).

```
// object to hold your data
function dataRow(value1,value2,value3) {
    this.name = value1;
    this.comparison = value2;
    this.value = value3;
}

$('#out').click(function(){   

    // create array to hold your data
    var dataArray = new Array();

    // iterate through rows of table
    for(var i = 1; i <= $("table tr").length; i++){

        // check if first field is used
        if($("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") select[class='field']").val().length > 0) {

            // create object and push to array
            dataArray.push(    
                new dataRow(
                    $("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") select[class='field']").val(),
                    $("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") select[class='comp']").val(),
                    $("table tr:nth-child(" + i + ") input").val())
            );
        }

    }

    // consider using a JSON library to do this for you
    for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++){
        var output = "";
        output = output + '{"name":"data' + (i + 1) + '.' + dataArray[i].name + '",';
        output = output + '"comparison":"data' + (i + 1) + '.' + dataArray[i].comparison + '",';
        output = output + '"value":"data' + (i + 1) + '.' + dataArray[i].value + '"}';
        alert(output);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to do here. First get the data into an array of objects, and secondly get the string representation.

I have not tested this, but it should give you a basic idea of what to do.

**Edit** Please take a look at this JS-Fiddle example I've made.  http://jsfiddle.net/4Nr9m/52/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var objects = new Array();
    $('table tr').each(function(key, value) {
        if($(this).find('td:first').not(':empty')) {
        //loop over the cells
        obj = {};
        $(this).find('td').each(function(key, value) {
                var label = $(this).parents('table').find('th')[key].innerHTML;
                obj[label] = value.innerHTML;

        });
        objects.push(obj);

        }
    });
    //get JSON.
    var json = objects.toSource();
    $('#result').append(json);
});
```

Comment: hey, thank you for this one. By the way, your link doesn't show the result. I only copy and paste the above code to show the result. And also, it doesn't skip the row if the first cell is empty. And one more thing, how to get the empty'{}' before the first row?.. thank you again for the idea and the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how it gets the blank object. Maybe you can debug it (with break points)on your site and with firefox and you'll see. It's difficult to debug jsfiddle.

Comment: Here you go. Needed `JSON.stringify()` and `.not(':empty').length > 0`   http://jsfiddle.net/4Nr9m/59/

Comment: @Keyo. hey, thanks fort this one. one more question. I'm using select tag and textbox. I want to get and displays only the selected value. How can i do that.

Comment: Try `obj[label] = $(value).find(':input')[0].val();`. There are plenty of docs around and you can just google `get input element value jquery` or something like that and find the methods you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

var a = [];
    a[0] = "data1.1 data1.2 data1.3"
    a[1] = "data1.6 data1.2 data1.3"
    var jsonobj = {};
    var c = []
    for (var i = 0;i

alert(c); //it will give ["{"name":"data1.1","comp...1.2","value":"data1.3"}", "{"name":"data1.6","comp...1.2","value":"data1.3"}"]

u have to include library for function from  JSON.stringify  from
 https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

hope this helps

Comment: thanks for the answer but it wont give good output if my data contains spaces. Maybe i just have to replace the split(' ') to (,). But thank you for the giving me an idea.

Comment: hey, it's working now... I did change your split(' ') to (,). thank you again.