# Add data dynamically to a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

This problem is related to my previous question in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892526/post-data-from-table-row-like-json-format). Now, what I'm trying to do is do the opposite thing. I have here a dynamic table (where you can add and delete rows) and whatever is the data that the user input in the latest use of table (trigger by a button) should be retrieve and be posted in the same table (if the same button is clicked).

Here's the code that I used to get the data from my dynamic table:

```
$('#tableSearchMainAccount1 tr').each(function(){  
var td = '';                   
   if ($(this).find("td:first").length > 0) {    // used to skip table header (if there is)            
      $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){
         td = td + $(this).text()+ ',';
      });
   td = td + $(this).find('input').val();
   filt[ctr]=td;
   ctr += 1;           
   } 
});   
alert (filt);  //alert output like  name,equals,ann,age,equals,11
```

Now, what I want to do is that when I click the button again, this previous input data will be posted again in my dynamic table.

My table is something that looks like this:

```
<table> <tr><th>field</th><th>comparison</th><th>value</th></tr>   
 <tr>
    <td>
      <select style="width:5em;" class="field">
        <option>name</option>
        <option>age</option>
        <option>sex</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select style="width:5em;" class = "comp">
        <option>equals</option>
        <option>starts with</option>
        <option>not equal to</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" class = 'value'></td>
    <td><img class="add" src="css/images/add.png" /></td> // this is used to add new row
 </tr>
</table>
```

The last data that a user input in the table should be displays in the table when table  shows again. How do I add the data to my dynamic table?

**EDIT:**
When the button is clicked, a dialog opens which contains my dynamic table and every time a user close the dialog, all the row from that table will be gone same as the data the user entered. I already create a variable that holds the latest inputted data in the table. So when the button click again, I want the table to generate or displays the last input data by the user. The output should be the same as the latest input data.

Comment: jayAnn, would it be possible to create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net -- just to clarify, what is that HTML code, is that the dynamic table? You want data from this table to go somewhere else?

Comment: My browser have a problem, i think. It won't show the jsfiddle. The data from the table is for my filter. I am creating a program that will filter the data from a server and i used the table to get the field, comparison and the value. What happened in my program now is that it can filter perfectly but everytime i clicked again the searcg button, my senior want to display my previous inputted data which i used in my previous filter. So that is my problem now. I dont know how to add the previous data in the dynamic table.

Comment: Very difficult to advise without seeing all the relevant (front end) code in how this system works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you had a button id `add` and you wanted to add a table row onto the end:

```
$('#add').on('click', function() {
   var $lastTr = $('table tr:last');
   $lastTr.clone().insertAfter($lastTr);
   $('#add', $lastTr).remove();
});
```

Using `.clone` to help us clone the last row, and appending it at the end.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/w9fXJ/

---

And just to pre-empt you're next question, here's the addition of **removing a row** ;-)

```
$('.remove_row').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/w9fXJ/1/

Comment: I already know how to do a dynamic table, thank you. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery.[prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and JQuery.[append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will help you

Comment: I know about append. My question is how to dynamically add the data to my dynamic table. I guess append is only used to add jquery element...to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.